# How can I get Apple mail or Outlook 2011 to look up SMIME encryption certificates for users?

Tags: email, ms-office, security, encryption, keychain

I want the ability to lookup an encryption certificate for SMIME in Outlook for recipients who have SMIME certs, but I just don't have their public key.

I noticed the keychain has a directory feature.  Can I use this to add a compatible directory to lookup their public key for SMIME encryption?

Answer (score 1):

According to the Apple TS article ["Using Keychain Access to search directory services for certificates"](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3915), if your Mac

- is configured to use a directory service,
- has the CA signing certificate trusted in either your login or the system keychains,
- has a valid signed user certificate with the appropriate attributes,

then Keychain Access can be configured (Preferences → General → Search directory services for certificates) to search for certificates on the configured directory service.  Mail.app will also automatically search for certificates as well.

Unfortunately, I haven't done this personally, so I can't vouch for how well it works or have any advice on any issues.  This reads to me like a feature designed to be used with a centrally-managed IT infrastructure with directory and certificate services.  It does not sound like it is designed to work outside that sort of environment.

Answer (score 0):

If your question were about PGP, then the answer would be you could download the recipient's public key from pgp.mit.edu , for example.

But as for S/MIME, the keystores are scattered.

It is weird, since it is straight-forward to publish [1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41446/how-do-i-share-my-s-mime-public-key)  your S/MIME certificate .

But the idea does not seem to have taken off. Case in point, here [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.tech.crypto/hNoWLUW8wxQ) is an announcement from 6/2/2011  , about [3](https://kuix.de/smime-keyserver/), which today (2014), seems to have 140 users.

References

[1 Sharing SMIME certs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41446/how-do-i-share-my-s-mime-public-key)

[2 from google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.tech.crypto/hNoWLUW8wxQ)

[3 https://kuix.de/smime-keyserver/](https://kuix.de/smime-keyserver/)